# Auto screen orientation is not working one user ser screen orientation android

Tags: android, eclipse, video, media-player

I have create a custom media player.In which there is a button for landscape and portrait mode. When player opens media player,its all feature works fine.But on click fullscreen button, i set media player to landscape mode. After this button click auto screen orientation is not working, only user can change orientation by clicking button(button to change landscape/portrait). Is there any method to work both auto screen orientation with button(button to change landscape/portrait)?

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you using a button?  Just let the user rotate the device!

Answer (score 0):

In your manifest file, you have given `permisssion` for `potrait` and `landscape`, So you have avoid that, instead of that do it in your `activity`.

Comment: i have not anything in manifest related to screen orientation.My activity in manifest is:   <activity
            android:name=".activity.VideoActivity"
            android:label="@string/video"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|uiMode|screenLayout" />